# cicle for is blocker, how to resolve it?

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem in objective-c with a `for` loop.  I want to wait the end of the loop before printing the elements on screen

```
 for (NSDictionary *item in allItems) {
        [self print:item];
};
```

when the loop ends, everything is print, but I would like printing during the loop.

how can i resolve it?

i tried with blocks without success

the print method:

```
-(void)print:(NSDictionary*)item{
   NSString *message=[item objectForKey:@"message"];
   if(message){
     int userid = 0;
     NSString *nome=[item objectForKey:@"name"];
     NSString *sesso=[item objectForKey:@"sex"];
     NSString *foto=[item objectForKey:@"photo"];
.........
```

Comment: your question makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your `-print:` method does, but I assume that it draws something on screen. Drawing in iOS and MacOS X doesn't happen immediately -- you draw into a graphics context that's managed by the graphics system, and that context is composed with others to generate the image that's ultimately drawn on the screen.

In other words, the screen drawing doesn't happen when you execute drawing commands, it happens when the graphics system periodically updates the screen. This is normal behavior -- it's not a problem.

Comment: @GabrieleCarbonai: and what does the method do after it assigned the dictionaries values to the variables?

Comment: just make graphics... take name message and picture and print in the screen... everything is from server, but before see all thing in the screen i have to wait the end of the loop.

Comment: but i can see the log during the loop

Comment: Right. The code executes, the drawing happens in your graphics context -- it just isn't composited to the screen until later. This is how drawing works, nothing to be concerned about.